# Error when publishing dynamic module contents Sitefinity

Tags: c#, exception, module, content-management-system, sitefinity

When I try to update the dynamic module contents and click on publish it is showing a popup with message **'The type initializer for '' threw an exception'** and I am not able to publish any content.

This is an inconsistent issue for me. It is weird that without doing any change at times this issues does not happen but it comebacks again. Can anyone please help me with this issue. Is this anything related to server update or server utilization because recently I added some more contents to the modules no other code changes or anything was done?

I found this link 'https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Uploading-images-error-Cannot-save-the-file-The-type-initializer-for-Module-threw-an-exception' but unfortunately, this did not solve my issue.

Comment: This happens to me as well, particularly in v.12.x Not sure what triggers it, probably a bug. What usually helps is a site restart - can you confirm that?

Comment: @VeselinVasilev yes site restart worked for me too thanks... But it is coming back often now.